# Plugin html-on-pages: URL not redirecting

Tags: redirect

We decided to not use the .html on pages http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-on-pages/
because its not supported already.

This plugin puts an .html extension to all the pages. But after deactivating it, the URL's are not redirecting to the proper page.

Need help? Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

That plugin was last updated 2008-11-20 and it's doubtful it will work with a new version of Wordpress and correctly revert URLs or changes it makes. Try resetting permalinks in Dashboard>>Settings>>Permalinks.

And, because your question is very specific to that plugin, you're much better off asking in the wordpress.org forums tagged for that plugin: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/html-on-pages

Comment: Thanks songdogtech. I doubt if someone will answer me in that support page. Anyway, what I am planning to do is just remove the suffix on the requested url.

Comment: The GUID shouldn't be used for generating URLs so even if the suffix is there is shouldn't matter and [is best left alone](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note).

Comment: s_ha_dum, you're right; I deleted reference to GUIDs in the database.